# Prove convergence in $L^1$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral

Let $(X, \mathscr{A}, \mu)$ be a finite measure space. Let $f_n \in L^1$. Assume $f_n \rightarrow f$ a.e. and there exist $p > 1$ and $c > 0$ such that $$||f_n||_p < c$$ for all $n$.

I want to show that $$f_n \rightarrow f \ \mbox{in} \ L^1, \ \mbox{i.e.,}\ \int_X |f_n - f| d\mu \rightarrow 0 \ \mbox{as} \ n \rightarrow \infty .$$

Since $f_n \rightarrow f$ a.e., I want to interchange limit and integration to get $$\lim \int |f_n - f| = \int \lim |f_n - f| = 0.$$
I think that the bounded condition $||f_n||_p < c$ might be used to obtain an integrable bound for $g_n = |f_n - f|.$ Then I will apply Dominated Convergence to interchange integration and limit. However, it seems that this approach does not work.

Any suggestion to solve the problem ?

Comment: You can show [$(f_n)$ is uniformly integrable](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1333361/suppose-mu-is-a-finite-measure-and-sup-n-int-f-n1-epsilon-d-mu-in) and appeal to [Vitali's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_convergence_theorem).

Comment: @DavidMitra So, since $$||f_n||_p < c \ \mbox{implies} \int |f_n|^p < c^p $$, then $$\sup_n \int |f_n|^{1 + (p-1)} < \infty \ \mbox{with} \ p-1 >0.$$ Then apply Vitali and the result is immediate !! Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If a sequence $f_n$ is bounded in $L^2$ and converges to zero a.e., then $f_n\to 0$ in $L^p$ for $0&lt;p&lt;2$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1068681/if-a-sequence-f-n-is-bounded-in-l2-and-converges-to-zero-a-e-then-f-n-to)